# Copy/paste disabled after running remote desktop in windows7

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, remote-desktop-services, copy

I have 64bit windows 7. When I run remote desktop to another server or computer, copy/paste disabled on whole of my PC!
I enabled copy/paste option on remote desktop, but it is not working.
I can not copy/paste between remote machine and my PC and I can not copy/paste anything in my PC.
When I disconnect from remote desktop, everything would be OK.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the following commands on your remote machine one by one.

```
Taskkill.exe /im rdpclip.exe 
Rdpclip.exe
```

But this is temporary fix. For permanent use online tools.